# How to define contrast colors in extending a palette in Angular Material theme

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, custom-theme

Angular Material Documentation for theming states the following to extend an existing palette for custom theming-

```
var neonRedMap = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('red', {
    '500': '#ff0000',
    'contrastDefaultColor': 'dark'
  });
```

In this, if i want to specify which color i want as the contrast using

```
'contrastLightColors': ['800']
```

is it possible? Doesn't seem to be working at all. Just defaults to black on giving contrastDefaultColor.
Is defining a whole new custom palette for this the only option?

I can't exactly use color css property since there are icons also that need to take that color. All those icons are web components (Angular 1.5x) so i want a centralised control over the colors.

What should i do?

Comment: don't use an array. Instead of that use like this  'contrastLightColors': '600 700 800 900 A200 A400 A700'